# Uniformly continuous function (onto) sends totally bounded set to totally bounded set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous and onto, $X\rightarrow Y$, where $X$ is totally bounded, then so is $Y$.

*Proof:

T.B. iff any sequence contains a Cauchy subsequence. Let there be a sequence in $Y$, then since $f$ is onto, the preimage is also a sequence in $X$. Since $X$ is totally bounded, there exists a Cauchy subsequence. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, that subsequence is mapped to a Cauchy sequence which is a subsequence from the original sequence in $Y$. So we are done.

**Correct?**

Comment: It does... one direction is pretty easy to show, the other direction you can use contrapositive.

Comment: The proof is  fine.

Comment: Thank you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more correct to say: suppose $(y_n)_n$ is a sequence in $Y$. Because $f$ is surjective we can pick $x_n \in X$ for all $n$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$, Then $(x_n)$ contains a Cauchy subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ and by uniform continuity of $f$, $(f(x_{n_k}))_k = (y_{n_k})_k$ is a Cauchy subsequence of $(y_n)_n$. QED.

You cannot say that the "preimage of a sequence is a sequence":
the type is wrong, as a sequence is not a subset, but a function, but also if $f$ were constant, e.g. the preimage is the whole space, not a sequence.

But it is true that there is a sequence in $X$ that maps onto the sequence in $Y$. Introducing some notation makes it easier to follow.

In essence your proof is fine. You could as an exercise show it from the definitions of totally bounded and uniform continuity: start with an $\varepsilon >0$, we get $\delta>0$ from the uniform continuity definition. Now a finite $\delta$-net of $X$ (which exists) maps to a finite $\varepsilon$-net of $Y$, using surjectivity.